# URL Rewriting in Global.asax - IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a fairly detailed problem with which I hope someone can help.  Basically, I have a .NET 4.0 website hosted on IIS7 that has some pages that necessitate URL rewriting.  In order to implement these features, I have added a method to my global.asax that maps the extension-less URLs to their proper ASPX pages, and then performs a context.RewritePath in order to display the correct page.

Initially, I called this method from application_BeginRequest.  However, we have some business necessary logging that occurs when Session_Start is called, and it appears that this logging is not always happening since the implementation of the URL rewriting in application_BeginRequest - Basically, every session gets logged in the DB, and after initial deployment of the URL rewriting, our session logs have dropped by about 20%, with no corresponding errors in the application log.  At the same time, our IIS logs seem to be showing a relatively unchanged amount of traffic, so to my eyes, it appears that the sessions are not instantiating properly.

As a workaround for this issue, I moved the URL rewriting from application_BeginRequest to application_AcquireRequestState, so that this code won't fire until after I'm (mostly) sure that the Session has started.  This works in my local dev environment and on our staging server (Windows Server 2008 - IIS 7 - .NET 4.5 Framework installed).  In the Production environment (Windows Server 2008 - IIS 7 - .NET 4.5 Framework), I get 404 errors when trying to browse to the extension-less URL to be re-written.

I'm completely stumped - I've verified that I'm using the Integrated app pool, my web.config has the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true" attribute, my IIS features include HTTP redirection and static file compression, but nothing appears to be working.  There's a hack that I found for using the Classic app pool, and creating extra script map handlers to handle wildcard URLs with no extensions, but I'm hesitant to put that in place in production.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would concentrate on why there was a 20% drop in session logs. Are you sure there wasn't also a drop in traffic? Are you using redirects for people coming to your site using the old .aspx Urls?  Perhaps you received more 404 traffic that would not trigger the Session_Start? Did Google Analytics confirm that traffic maintained normal levels after the UrlRewite was put into place?  You could also use [IIS Log Parser](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2010/04/log-parser-22) to filter out static files and query 200 vs 404s from the log files to get a better sense of actual traffic.